# Display another text when CheckBox is (un)checked

Tags: javascript, checkbox

It should be quite simple. You have the following text:

> Your scream: Whoops!

And when you check the checkbox below that says

> Scream "yay" instead!

the word “Whoops!” should change to “Yay!”:

> Your scream: Yay!

So my body is (I want to do it with a function):

```
Your scream: <script>GiveMeSomeScream()</script>!<hr>
<input type="checkbox" name="whatever" id="ScreamYay"> Scream "yay" instead!
```

But I’m having problems with the actual script. Here’s what I tried first:

```
function GiveMeSomeScream()
{  if (document.GetElementById('ScreamYay').checked == "true")
{  document.write("Yay");
}  else
{  document.write("Whoops");
}}
```

But it just wouldn’t work. So I expanded it like this:

```
var yay = document.getElementById('ScreamYay').checked
function GiveMeSomeScream()
{  if (yay == "true")
{  document.write("Yay");
}  else
{  document.write("Whoops");
}}
```

Now it gives “Whoops” every time (even if I make the checkbox checked defaultly), and that’s pretty much it.

I know it’s ridiculous I can’t even handle a checkbox, but still I would be glad for any help.

Comment: Boolean constants in JavaScript are `true` and `false`, no quotes. You generally don't need to explicitly compare to the constants anyway.

Comment: Also, your use of `document.write()` here is going to cause fundamental failure: the call will wipe out the whole page, leaving just "Yay" or "Whoops".

Answer (score 1):

Change `if (yay == "true")` to `if (yay)`

Comment: Didn’t help, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The value returned from `document.getElementById('elementID').checked` will be a boolean. This is further explained [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp). To use that, you can simply test against the value using `if(yay === true)` or `if(yay)` as @Alex suggests. As for using `document.write`, you need to include the html tags (markup) like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like following
you have to add onchange function on checkbox tag.
also document.GetElementById is wrong
document.getElementbyId is right
finally
document.getElementById("ScreamYay").checked == "true" is wrong
document.getElementById("ScreamYay").checked == true is right

```
function GiveMeSomeScream()
{  if (document.getElementById('ScreamYay').checked == true)
{  document.write("Yay");
}  else
{  document.write("Whoops");
}}
```